# Saving OAuth2 Login User in Database in Spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-security, google-oauth

I have a google authentication setup with spring boot v3. I have setup the authentication flow configuration as to save the authenticated google users some details in the local db with a customOAuth2UserService class with the oAuth2Login configuration in spring securities securityFilterChain bean. The authentication is succeeding and the code in oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler is executing, but the details are not stored in the db, when I debug, the debugger doesn't move into customOAuth2UserUserService class. what I'm probably doing wrong, please help me to resolve or further debug this issue.

**SecurityFilterChain**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAndLoginFilter jwtAndLoginFilter;
    private final CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;
    private final OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    private final OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(JwtAndLoginFilter jwtAndLoginFilter,
    CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService, OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler,
    OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler) {
        this.jwtAndLoginFilter = jwtAndLoginFilter;
        this.customOAuth2UserService = customOAuth2UserService;
        this.oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler = oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
        this.oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler = oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf
                        .disable())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin.disable())
                .httpBasic(httpBasic -> httpBasic.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/auth/signup", "/api/v1/auth/signin").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/oauth2/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> {
                    oauth2.authorizationEndpoint(oauthEndpoint -> {
                        oauthEndpoint.baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
                        .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository());
                    })
                    .redirectionEndpoint(redirectionEndpoint -> redirectionEndpoint.baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*"))
                    .userInfoEndpoint(userInfoEndpoint -> userInfoEndpoint.userService(customOAuth2UserService))
                    .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);
                })
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAndLoginFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

**CustomOAuth2UserService**

```
@Service
public class CustomOAuth2UserService extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {

    private final OAuth2UserRepository oAuth2UserRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CustomOAuth2UserService(OAuth2UserRepository oAuth2UserRepository) {
        this.oAuth2UserRepository = oAuth2UserRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        OAuth2User oAuth2User = super.loadUser(oAuth2UserRequest);

        try {
            return processOAuth2User(oAuth2UserRequest, oAuth2User);
        } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Throwing an instance of AuthenticationException will trigger the OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause());
        }
    }

    private OAuth2User processOAuth2User(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User oAuth2User) {
        OAuth2UserInfo oAuth2UserInfo = OAuth2UserInfoFactory.getOAuth2UserInfo(oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId(), oAuth2User.getAttributes());

        if(!StringUtils.hasLength(oAuth2UserInfo.getEmail())) {
            throw new OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingException("Email not found from OAuth2 provider");
        }

        Optional<com.solutions.computic.server.security.oauth2.entities.OAuth2User> userOptional = oAuth2UserRepository.findByEmail(oAuth2UserInfo.getEmail());
        com.solutions.computic.server.security.oauth2.entities.OAuth2User user;
        if(userOptional.isPresent()) {
            user = userOptional.get();
            if(!user.getProvider().equals(AuthProvider.valueOf(oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId()))) {
                throw new OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingException("Looks like you're signed up with " +
                        user.getProvider() + " account. Please use your " + user.getProvider() +
                        " account to login.");
            }
            user = updateExistingUser(user, oAuth2UserInfo);
        } else {
            user = registerNewUser(oAuth2UserRequest, oAuth2UserInfo);
        }

        return UserPrincipal.create(user, oAuth2User.getAttributes());
    }

    private com.solutions.computic.server.security.oauth2.entities.OAuth2User registerNewUser(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2UserInfo oAuth2UserInfo) {
        var user = new com.solutions.computic.server.security.oauth2.entities.OAuth2User();

        user.setProvider(AuthProvider.valueOf(oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId()));
        user.setProviderId(oAuth2UserInfo.getId());
        user.setName(oAuth2UserInfo.getName());
        user.setEmail(oAuth2UserInfo.getEmail());
        return oAuth2UserRepository.save(user);
    }

    private com.solutions.computic.server.security.oauth2.entities.OAuth2User updateExistingUser(com.solutions.computic.server.security.oauth2.entities.OAuth2User existingUser, 
    OAuth2UserInfo oAuth2UserInfo) {
        existingUser.setName(oAuth2UserInfo.getName());
        return oAuth2UserRepository.save(existingUser);
    }
}
```

**OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler**

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private final List<String> authorizedRedirectUris;
    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private final HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;

    @Autowired
    public OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler(@Value("${authorizedRedirectUris}") List<String> authorizedRedirectUris, TokenProvider tokenProvider,
    HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository) {
        this.authorizedRedirectUris = authorizedRedirectUris;
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository = httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(request, response, authentication);

        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            log.debug("Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to " + targetUrl);
            return;
        }

        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request, response);
        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

    protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        Optional<String> redirectUri = CookieUtils.getCookie(request, HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository.REDIRECT_URI_PARAM_COOKIE_NAME)
                .map(Cookie::getValue);

        if(redirectUri.isPresent() && !isAuthorizedRedirectUri(redirectUri.get())) {
            throw new FoodDeliveryException("Sorry! We've got an Unauthorized Redirect URI and can't proceed with the authentication");
        }

        String targetUrl = redirectUri.orElse(getDefaultTargetUrl());

        String token = tokenProvider.createToken(authentication);

        return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(targetUrl)
                .queryParam("token", token)
                .build().toUriString();
    }

    protected void clearAuthenticationAttributes(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        super.clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
        httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository.removeAuthorizationRequestCookies(request, response);
    }

    private boolean isAuthorizedRedirectUri(String uri) {
        URI clientRedirectUri = URI.create(uri);

        return authorizedRedirectUris
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(authorizedRedirectUri -> {
                    // Only validate host and port. Let the clients use different paths if they want to
                    URI authorizedURI = URI.create(authorizedRedirectUri);
                    if(authorizedURI.getHost().equalsIgnoreCase(clientRedirectUri.getHost())
                            && authorizedURI.getPort() == clientRedirectUri.getPort()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: `oauth2Login` is based on sessions, disabling CSRF protection is not reasonable. Also, if you intend to save some data about users from an external OpenID Provider and later use this data to enrich it / link it to your own entities, you should probably consider use an authorization server of your own: use external OPs as identity provider for your authorization server and use this authorization server as "user-service" for the rest of your app (in your DB, use user subject from your authorization server as reference and call authorization server REST API when you need details).